# Reducir borde de botón css html

Tags: html, css

Realmente no sé mucho de código `css` o `html`, pero me parece que el borde es demasiado grande y no se como reducirlo de forma que sólo cubra lo suficiente el botón, así se ve en el sitio móvil y en la web de escritorio hay mucho espacio entre el botón y el siguiente objeto.

No soy programador web, sólo lo hago por apoyo a alguien.

https://www.grupoarlo.com/arlo-concepto-residencial

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
<html lang="en"><head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
 
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e3bd1c;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 23px 33px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que es posible que sea el tamaño de la imagen.

Comment: Quieres reducir el borde o el espacio entre el borde y el texto

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres reducir el borde, modifica donde dice `border 3px solid transparent` y cambia de 3px a 1px.

Si quieres reducir el espacio entre el borde y el texto cambia donde dice  `padding: 23px 33px;`; el primer grupo de numero modifica el espaciado de arriba/abajo el segundo grupo de numero modifica el espacio de izquierda/derecha.